# Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. CryptoCompare.com API

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, axios

I had that error in my web application :

> Failed to load https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

I want to retrieve some data form cryptocompare API.
Funny thing is that when I paste url in my browser :
https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/
I get what I want.

Also when I send Get method from Postman with only above URL and I got everythink I want.

The problem is when I want to use axios library (https://github.com/axios/axios) for javascript.

And when i wrote that function :

```
import axios from 'axios';

class CryptoCompareApi {
    getAllCoins() {
        return axios.get('https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/');
    }
}

export default new CryptoCompareApi();
```

And use it :

```
const coins = CryptoCompareApi.getAllCoins()
            .then((response) => {
                this.props.changeAllCryptos(response);
            });
```

I get above error.

Is there something I do wrong ? 
Or maybe I should use some workaround ?

As a addition I can't access BE side.

Answer (score 0):

try using the min-api: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/

DUE TO ABUSIVE USAGE, IF YOU WANT YOUR CLIENTS TO DIRECTLY USE OUR APIS, USE THE MIN-API PATH. (THE HEADER Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is only set on min-api paths)